# Struts 2 validator

Tags: java, struts2, validation

I have a problem with struts2 validator(i m new in struts2).

I have 2 buttons on my page and each one validate 2 commons rules and the the second one add another specific rule.

Here is my configuration:

my action is VPJ001Action.java

**`struts.xml`** configuration file look like this:

```
 <action name="VPJ001" class="VPJ001Action">
     <result>/jsp/test.jsp</result>
 </action>
 <action name="VPJ001ValidationAction" method="validation" class="VPJ001Action">
     <result name="PAGE_VPJ002" type="chain">VPJ002!execute</result>
     <result>/jsp/test1.jsp</result>
 </action>
 <action name="VPJ001DiffusionMailAction" method="diffusionMail" class="VPJ001Action">
     <result>/jsp/test.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

my first button invoke `VPJ001ValidationAction` and the second one invoke `VPJ001DiffusionMailAction`

my validator configuration:

**`VPJ001Action-validation.xml`** contains 2 commons rules:

```
<validators>
    <field name="bassin">
       <field-validator type="required">
         <message key="validation.bassin.requis"/>
       </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="moisAValider">
        <field-validator type="required">
           <message key="validation.mois.requis"/>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

and

**`VPJ001Action-VPJ001DiffusionMailAction-validation.xml`** contain the specific rule:

```
<validators>
<field name="moisAValider">
    <field-validator type="regex" short-circuit="true">
          <param name="expression">.*[\*]$</param>
          <message key="validation.mois.valide"/>
     </field-validator>
</field>
</validators>
```

**Here is the result:**

when i click on the 2 buttons, i have a popup with the 2 commons rule because i don't select anything on the page, its work fine.

when i select a bassin and a moisAValider if i click on validate button, all is ok, i m redirect on the good page

when i select a bassin and a moisAValider if i click on diffusionMailbutton, the page is refresh and a popup is open with my specific rule (regex not respected) but the page have been reloaded!

**I want to have this scenario:**

If i click on the validate button without select anything, i want a popup with the 2 commons rules not respected

and if i click on the diffusionMailButton without select anything, i want a popup with the 2 commons rules not respected and the specific rule,

does it possible?

I want that the validation for the specific rule will be done in client side and not in server side, because if its done in server side, the page is reloaded and all my list are empty...i need to reload all list and its not necessary if all validator can be done in client side...

thank for your help!

Comment: How could you click on 2 buttons at the same time?

Comment: Where do you see i want to click on 2 button at the same time? I speak about two different button. Validation button and diffusion Mail button;) and each one have 2 commons validator on the second one another validation

Comment: I don't see any of them, also could you change the question so, it will be one button?

Comment: The begginning of the question i say "i have 2 button on my page" when i click on the first one i check if listbox are correctly set to pass to the next page. And when i click on the second button i check the two listbox and i need to check if the value have * at the end. I want to use validator to do this. But when i put my validator configuration when i click on the first button its check the 3 rules! But i want to check only the 2 first one. In my configuration i have correctly associate my action to the validator. Thats why i ask someone if i do a mistake in my configuration. Thanks

Comment: No, you have written _I have 2 buttons_, and if you don't see a difference the question makes no sense. I could ask you a thousand questions to clarify your question, without it is impossible to help. Read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: I m french and not english fluent so i do my best... i don t knwo how to explain to you that i have a page with 2 distincts button...i think its not difficult to understand, its the firsttime that someone play on the words. So if you can't help me because its not clear, sorry and thank you to try ;).

Comment: @RomanC i have find a solution ;) thank to try to help me and sorry if i m not clear. I will try to do my best next time ;). best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have find my solution.

Because validator don't do what i want, i  add only 2 validators for the 2 buttons (those validators are client side validation) and i have add one more validator using `<field-validator type="expression">` to call a java method. This method check the requested action and return true or false when needed.

The last point is when this method return false, i'm redirected to the jsp and all my selectboxs are refreshed and empty, this is because when i submit my form all lists are not pass to the server. I need to add hidden input to my form with the list. Because i use List i have done a converter that serialize the result to have only one hidden input like this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="listeBassinSurveillance" id="formulaireVPJ_listeBassinSurveillance" value="H4sIAAAAAAAAAJ2WS4/bVBTHbzJ5dR5tmCmdMtMBS0gVCCWTGdJ.....">
```

and when i submit the form, the value is deserialized and all values are put in the list in the action, so when i refreshed the jsp, all my lists are not empty!

this seems complicated but very simple to realized and clear.

thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you want client side validation why don't you use javascript or jquery for the same and your problem will be resolved.
I could have commented but I can't. Below are the links for your reference.

[javascript form validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)

[jquery example](http://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/)

there is a way in struts2 with javascript ajax

in your struts.xml you can define your method result as:-

```
<result type="stream">
  <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
  <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
 </result>
```

and then in your action method you can check whatever you want to check and then if that validation is correct then set like below:-

```
this.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(SUCCESS.getBytes()));
```

and if validation failes then

```
this.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(ERROR.getBytes()));
```

that's all from struts side.
in your on form submit in java-script you can do somewhat like this

```
$.ajax({
                        traditional: true,
                        type: "POST", 
                        url : ctxPath + "/yourActionName",
                        data : "yourField="+value,
                        dataType: "text",
                        success : function(data, success) {
                            if(data.indexOf("success")==-1){
                               alert("Action returned Error");
                                 return false;
                            }else{
                                alert("Action returned Success");

                            }
                        },
                    });
```

Comment: I undestand your point but if struts give me the possibility to do this, i want to re use same popup to show error message, and same architectur for all error message. If i could nt i will try with jquery